# React server components and Page transition interactivity in NextJs

Tags: reactjs, next.js, gsap, next.js13, react-server-components

I'm building a web app using nextjs 13 with the app directory. I want the pages to have cool page transitions and items smoothly appearing as you scroll and so forth using mostly gsap animation.

My question is, can I use server components for all the components and then just sprinkle that animation stuff on top somehow (using refs or something, I don't know) or would this require me to use the 'use client' directive for all components that will have this type of animation?

My big issue is thinking in a PHP way where you'd use JavaScript on the client to do things like `getElementById()` and add interactivity that way.

I want to understand how to use server components in this way where you'd want the component data on the server but also have that component have some interactive animation. Any pointers in the right direction would be massively helpful here. thanks.

Comment: Hello. I am currently on the same task. I found this video, maybe this will help you.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?app=desktop&v=ugCN_gynFYw


Animations usually applied on the client side. You can load the server component, but you need CSS and other client-side libs to animate transitions.


Also, please read the "formatting your questions" guide, because it's inconvenient to read your question. No paragraphs, no code formatting.

Comment: Thanks, Victor, and sorry for the poorly formatted question. I'll run through the YouTube video and hopefully get clarification on some things.

Comment: yeah, now the question is much better